# Implementing expiring locks (or semaphores) using postgres

Tags: postgresql, redis

I have the following table

```
Tasks
   max_solvers int, # Maximum number of users that can solve this task (e.g. survey)
   current_solvers int[], # List of user ids that solved this task (e.g. already took the survey)
   state char[1], # If the task is solved or not, this variable can be used to show tasks to users to solve.
```

Question:
Example: Let's say a task can be solved by only 3 users (e.g. max_solvers = 3)

So any query that does the following will not work:

```
  select * from tasks where task.state = 'NOT_SOLVED'
```

Because we might show that task to (e.g. 100) users and only 3 of them can solve and other 97 users work will be wasted.

One (of the possible) ways to solve this would be using semaphores. A task can be shown only to max_solvers - array_length(current_solvers).

Semaphore will work for the most part. If a user is shown a task but ends up not solving (e.g. their phone died). It would be nice to have a expiring sempahores.

Actual question :)

Is it possible to implement expiring semaphores (or expiring ) locks using postgres. I know postgres has Advisory locks but they don't automatically expire.

One way to simulate expiring locks (or serializing access) is previously discussed [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/97261)

Is it possible to extend that answer to implement expiring semaphores.

Or is it better to rely on other system that can solve this more effectively (e.g. [redis refreshing semaphores](https://redislabs.com/ebook/part-2-core-concepts/chapter-6-application-components-in-redis/6-3-counting-semaphores/6-3-1-building-a-basic-counting-semaphore/))

Thanks!

Comment: What if their phone doesn't die but they get distracted watching funny cat videos?  What if someone submits a task, but after they lost the lock?  Do you need to give them some descriptive error message (which means you need to retain enough info to do so), or just DK them, or what?

Comment: Yeah. The expectation here is if a user accepts to solve a task. They have a timewindow to solve that task (These are online tasks). 

If they submit after that time window there will be an error message